# redis key update notification in rest api

Tags: rest, asynchronous, redis

I would like to utilize key update notification mechanism of redis in a Http based rest api implemented in java.

- Once a request is received in http rest api, it publishes details to be handled by an async process and waits for associated unique key notification from redis.
- Async process after computation will create an entry in redis db with same unique key.
- rest api receives unique key notification and replies back with http response.

Is this possible with redis, or there is a better option to get notified inside http request/reply implementation?

Comment: Does it have to be async? Redis is generally fast enough for the vast majority of synchronous use cases.

Comment: async part is needed for scalability of service plus keeping processing logic outside.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is fine as long as you make sure your async process that receives the message and provides the result is fast enough to not exceed any configured request timeouts (especially under foreseen load). When you cannot guarantee that - you can consider using polling strategy:

1. return an async job identifier and let the client ask for its result, or
2. define a timeout for the async job to complete - if it provides the result in that time - return it, otherwise return async job identifier as above.